# Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We'll be entering public beta soon, so we need to get word out to the rest of Stack Exchange about Mythology Stack Exchange. One of the best ways of doing this is with Community Promotion Ads.

Here is part of the canonical spiel given on meta posts on graduated sites where we submit our ads for voting (six upvotes and our ad is shown on the site), repurposed for a different use:

> #### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will
>   show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this
>   question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are
>   provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be
>   shown.
>
> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to
>   visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following
>   things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - useful tools or resources for physics research
> - interesting articles or findings for the curious
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your
>   community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote
>   information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's
>   interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to
>   join.
>
> #### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other
>   things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads
>   every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served
>   their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This
>   helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject
>   matter of the community, but to the current status of the community.
>   We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an
>   ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very
>   valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good
>   idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the
>   process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale
>   after a year of exposure.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

For more information, see [What's the best way to create a community ad for a beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247037/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-community-ad-for-a-beta-site).

I invite everyone to submit ideas for our ad as answers, following the above guidelines.

Comment: Hopefully, all of our art skills are good!

Comment: @PythonMaster [I'm not too good at Paint.](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/119/make-some-community-ads/219#219)

Comment: Try a Photo Editor instead. The art of photo editing.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the subject of these community bulletin ads have to be at least *roughly* within the topic space of that site (i.e. don't be posting this everywhere).

Comment: So what now for 2K16?

Answer (score 14):

Here's one for SciFi.SE and Movies.SE:

[image: Meet the Real Thor: Join the Mythology Stack Exchange!]

I think it's great because it takes a subject matter that's relevant to those two sites and connects it to our site.

I can change the font and/or proportions to make the ad better.

Comment: I like it. Nice.

Comment: [Posted.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/community-promotion-ads-2015/6897#6897)

Comment: [also posted on Movies.se](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1799/21177)

Comment: Recreate it so that it fits the sizes for 2016

Answer (score 10):

Another one for [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

Comment: This would be great on arqade,  as well.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@femtoRgon I was thinking of an Age of Mythology themed one for Arqade, but this could work too. And of course, nothing stopping us from posting different variations and letting the Arqade crowd decide which one they prefer (if any).

Comment: [Posted on Meta RPG](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/5571/22938). If you have an account on the site, you might want to give it a little boost.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some suggestions for sites where ads for this site might be relevant:

- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) - spin it as "look at how much of the English language comes from mythology!" or maybe how cool King Arthur is or something
- [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) and [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) - assuming the idea of their stories being "myths" doesn't give them aneurysms
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) - "Did you know that the character Thor first appeared in Norse mythology? Come to Mythology.SE to learn more!" (or something along those lines but less silly) / "Did you know that Disney's *Hercules* misrepresents the myth of Hercules in just about every possible way? Come to Mythology.SE to learn more!" (and so forth)
- [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) - maybe there's some Classicists or other mythologists that we could rope in from over there?

Comment: Another SciFi spin: "Mythology.SE: Your great-great-great-great-great-great-grandfather's Science Fiction & Fantasy"

Comment: I think History.SE might be interested. Perhaps also Philosophy.SE.

Comment: [I posted a community ad on C.SE](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4555/3961) when we were still in commitment phase. It got one up and one down. Out of 10 answers for this year's, only two have made it so far.

Comment: I think it has to be a graduated site though.

Comment: Right, only graduated sites run these ads => no History or Philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one looking toward Arqade.

[image: Mythology Stack Exchange]

FF6 Seems like a good one to hit that retro vibe, while still being pretty ubiquitous.  The FF series always throws around a lot of references to mythology without background on them.

And I like "Baby Got Backstory", or "Got Backstory?", or something like that. Gets across what we're offering for movies/games/etc.

If anyone wishes to reuse or improve anything here:  [grab the .xcf](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jzp8lx3fjuori9n/AAA5rFuBZR9a03Q13ZkDWWmia?dl=0)

Comment: If someone posts this at Arqade, you'd certainly get my upvote over there too.

Comment: @Arperum - Thanks for the support.  I've posted it over there now: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10551/33831

Answer (score 5):

### Here's a generic:

[image: Mythology.SE]

It's nice for Christianity or Judaism because it doesn't say anything one way or the other. Just the site name and an epitomizing picture. For those interested, the font is Lithos Pro. If this gets enough votes, I'll post it on Christianity.SE

---

I've put it on [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4588/3961). We'll see what happens.

Comment: [PSD if you want to fiddle](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92136005/SO/mythology.psd).

Comment: It has gotten the necessary votes and is now displaying on the C.SE site. [Snapshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/A4V8B.png)

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the movie inspired one, but going for something generic.

[image: Mythology Stack Exchange]

Reasoning:  I really like the [generic Space.SE ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWTVN.png).  Seems to me like Mythology sells itself to some extent.  As long as we catch peoples eye, and they know we're here.  Might be my biases showing.

At first, was mucking about with [this image](http://www.howarddavidjohnson.com/Odin_and_Sleipnir_.jpg), just to try things, and rather liked the result, but I assume copyright *is* an issue.

If anyone wishes to reuse or improve anything here:  [grab the .xcf](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jzp8lx3fjuori9n/AAA5rFuBZR9a03Q13ZkDWWmia?dl=0)

Answer (score 3):

### Another Generic, but it entices and intrigues.

[image: Did you hear what happened to Zeus?]

Maybe the tag line should be split into two lines so that the text can be bigger. Comments?

Comment: [PSD if you want to fiddle](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92136005/SO/mythology.psd).

Answer (score -2):

Here's one for SciFi.SE and Movies.SE:

[image: Visit Mythology.SE]

My MS Paint art could be replaced with something better ;)

Comment: Looks good, but here's what Google Image search tells me:  "Best guess for this image: oberyn martell game of thrones".  I figured it out in the end, but that might say something about how recognizable the character is...

Comment: @femtoRgon Heh, I guess the actors do look pretty similar.

Comment: Yeah, he does!  Took a bit of looking at the imdb page of the actor from Game of Thrones to realize I was barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I'm sorry: from which TV show is this?

Comment: @plannapus Stargate

Comment: Isn't every single character of that show based on Mythology?

Comment: @plannapus Yes but Baal was the most enigmatic

Comment: @curiousdannii I think that's a matter of opinion. Anubis was quite mysterious, I think. But his Stargate representation is not very recognizable.

Answer (score -6):

A crude attempt using Paint that matches all the major requirements:

[image]

All opinions on this proposed ad please post as a comment under my own answer. Due to the comments to this answer, I declare this answer to be:

***An Totally Unfit Answer... Do not Make one of this quality!!!***

Comment: I have to say, it looks a little amateur-ish compared to some of the other community ads by other beta sites.

Comment: It was a crude attempt. I will leave it there as an example of what the ad should not look like.

Comment: I like the concept.

Comment: Obiously the concept is too good but need better graphics