# Site Promotion: reaching out to bloggers

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I think its time to focus again on promoting the site. We have [some successful community promotion ads](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/62), and a few people have been [submitting links to reddit](http://www.reddit.com/domain/mythology.stackexchange.com/), but I think it would be great to expand our efforts and try a new promotion tactic.

## Why bother promoting the site?

I just think it would be interesting if we could get 3-4 people to add a fresh perspective to questions and answers. I've enjoyed reading questions and answers from people who are new to the site, and I would love for that to continue. I don't think any promotion effort will magically boost us to 10 questions per day (and therefore graduation), [but that shouldn't be our immediate goal anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites).

## Why bloggers?

For a number of reasons:

1. They're already online, so they could adapt easily to the Stack Exchange model.
2. They've already shown that they can write quality content for an online audience (if we recruit the right bloggers).
3. Some bloggers might want to promote their blog through an online community, which would be fine if they did so in their profile.
4. When people go online to talk about mythology, it's often because they don't know anyone "in real life" with whom they can have in depth conversation about it. I have a feeling that many bloggers will be enthusiastic about participating in an online community, especially one like ours that likes to have indepth conversations about texts.

## How will this work?

In my answer to this question, I'm going to start a list of high quality mythology blogs and websites that I am aware of. The answer will be community wiki, so please add any blogs that you know of.

Next, choose one blog, and email/communitate with that blogger using one of the following strategies:

1. Just invite them to join the site.
2. If the blogger has ever used their blog to ask a mythology question, ask their question for them and tell them about it. See this Stack Exchange blog post: [Helping the Experts get Answers](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/).
3. Invite them to answer an unanswered question.
4. Ask them their opinion on an answer that related to their interests.

This should be an interesting experiment, and hopefully it yields results.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starter list; I would appreciate it if people added more blogs to it:

1. http://www.norsemyth.org/
2. https://thehistoryofwesternthought.wordpress.com/
3. http://openmythsource.com/myth-lab/
4. http://bettermyths.com/
5. add more blogs here

I've already contacted a few people (not on the list), and it would be great if more people contributed to the effort.

Comment: Maybe some would disagree, but how about [Myths RETOLD!](http://bettermyths.com/)?  Goofy and irreverent, yeah, but nothing wrong with making things accessible and having some fun, if you ask me.  I'm sure there's a good amount of research that goes into his work.

Comment: @femtoRgon I added it to the list; I can contact that blogger if you want. I agree with you: (s)he probably puts a lot of research in their blog, and is worth contacting.

Comment: Glad I'm not way off base there.  Sure, if you're up for reaching out to people, go ahead.  I'm not really a good evangelist.