# List of websites that link to Mythology SE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

One way to promote the site is to get other websites to link to us. I created this question to keep track of which websites link to out website. If you would like to help promote the site, please link to us, or ask other websites to do the same.

(We're discussing how to increase activity in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23512692#23512692). Please participate.)

Answer (score 2):

## Social Networks

1. [Several community promotion ads on various Stack Exchange sites](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/62).
2. [Some people have submitted links to our questions on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/domain/mythology.stackexchange.com/).

## Websites and Blogs

1. Our very own Arthur George's [Mythology Matters blog](https://mythologymatters.wordpress.com/).

## Forums and Newsgroups

1. I posted a link to our site on [the Alt.Mythology newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.mythology/oXO9E3bUM4I/VDe--kWsCwAJ).

Answer (score 1):

I have a link to you on my blog [We Are Star Stuff](https://earthandstarryheaven.com/).